# Eliminate phase and compare arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I assume this has been asked before but I really don't know how to phrase my search so I create a new question.
I have a numpy array, e.g.:

```
A = np.array([[1, 0],[0,1],[1,-1],[-1,1],[1j,1],[1,-1j]])
```

So this has 6 lines, however, 2 sets of 2 are the same just with a phase:
line 3 and 4

```
[1,-1] = -1*[-1,1]
```

or line 5 and 6

```
[1j,1] = 1j*[1,-1j]
```

is there a function `funct` or code that let's me find those "duplicates" and eliminate them. 
So it should give me the result A_new of the form:

```
A_new = funct(A)
```

results in

```
A_new = np.array([[1, 0],[0,1],[1,-1],[1j,1]])
```

For my example I can do it manually, but I also have arrays that are much much larger and not as nicely sorted as this example.

Thanks and apologies if this has been asked before.

Markus

Comment: Am I right in assuming that you consider two pairs equal if they are equal after multiplication by any value from `[1, -1, 1j, -1j]`? Or would you have other use cases where some other criteria would have to hold for equality? Like modulus?

Comment: yeah it's only those 4 instances

Comment: I was thinking about a solution using `np.unique`, but that requires also knowing how these values would be sorted. For two pairs `[a,b]` and `[c,d]`, how would you decide if `[a,b] < [c,d]`? Or is that undefined (in which case `np.unique` won't work)

Comment: I don't think sorting works on this complex numbers and even if it would e.g. use the absolute it is always either 1 or sort(2). After your first comment I wrote something that works but is incredibly ugly and slow, see below.

Comment: sqrt(2) , not sort(2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a mathematical way to do it. If any two pair of values p1, p2 in the array A are 'same but with a phase', then if `c=p1/p2`, then `c[0]==c[1]`. We may do this in a vectorized way using matrix multiplication:

```
import numpy as np
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

def phasefilter(A):
    A_0, A_1 = A[:,0].reshape(-1,1), A[:,1].reshape(-1,1)
    B_0, B_1 = 1/(A_0.T), 1/(A_1.T)
    C_0, C_1 = A_0@B_0, A_1@B_1
    phasemap = C_0==C_1
    return np.array([A[i] for i,(pmap) in enumerate(phasemap) if phasemap[i][np.arange(i+1,A.shape[0])].sum()==0])
```

I imported warnings since when dividing two pairs of values, we may divide by zero.

```
A = np.array([[1, 0],[0,1],[1,-1],[-1,1],[1j,1],[1,-1j]])
print('Out:\n',phasefilter(A))
A = np.array([[2,3],[1,2],[-2,-3],[4,-5],[6,7],[-5,4]])
print('Out:\n',phasefilter(A))
A = np.array([[2,3],[1,2],[-2,-3],[4,-5],[2,3],[-5,4]])
print('Out:\n',phasefilter(A))
```

Output:

```
Out:
 [[ 1.+0.j  0.+0.j]
 [ 0.+0.j  1.+0.j]
 [-1.+0.j  1.+0.j]
 [ 1.+0.j -0.-1.j]]
Out:
 [[ 1  2]
 [-2 -3]
 [ 4 -5]
 [ 6  7]
 [-5  4]]
Out:
 [[ 1  2]
 [ 4 -5]
 [ 2  3]
 [-5  4]]
```

**Edit:** While the above method is easy, it doesn't scale well to larger dimensions, so here's an even more generalized solution, for any number of dimensions:

```
def phasefilter(A, P=np.array([[1,-1,1j,-1j]])):
    N, M = A.shape[0], A.shape[1]
    AT = A.reshape(N,M,1)
    PM = np.swapaxes(AT@P, 1, 2).reshape(-1,M)
    return A[[i for i in range(N) if not (PM[4*i]==PM[4*(i+1):]).all(axis=1).any()]]
```

Comment: correction: also just works for the current dimension, e.g. if you try: `A = np.array([[1, 0, 0],[0,-1j,1],[0,1,1j],[1,0,1j],[0,1j,1]])` it isn't working (line 2 and 3 is the same but doesn't get detected). Could you elaborate how to extend it?

Comment: @Markus I edited in a more general solution, that should work for any dimension. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Deduplication in Numpy is straightforward:

```
values = np.array([[1, 0],[0,1],[1,-1],[-1,1],[1j,1],[1,-1j]])
deduped = numpy.unique(values)
```

But of course `unique` uses normal Python equivalence to compare values. Since your values are pairs of where `[1,-1] == [-1,1]`, you need to get numpy to use a different equality implementation.

```
import numpy as np


class Pair:
    def __init__(self, ab):
        self.a, self.b = ab

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.a, self.b) in [(other.a*x, other.b*x) for x in [1, -1, 1j, -1j]]

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return False

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'[{self.a}, {self.b}]'


xs = [Pair(x) for x in [[1, 0], [0, 1], [1, -1], [-1, 1], [1j, 1], [1, -1j]]]
values = np.array(xs)
print(np.unique(values))
```

Here, the array is constructed from a list of `Pair` objects, which have the equality operation defined on them with `__eq__`. Note that `__lt__` is also defined, because `np.unique` works by sorting the values. You should replace it with a valid "less than" operation, if one is defined on your pairs, to avoid unreliable results.

I added `__repr__` so that the resulting list of `Pair` objects prints nicer.

Result:

```
[[1, 0] [0, 1] [1, -1] [1j, 1]]
```

Comment: It works fine for sets of two numbers like in my example but breaks down for some reason if the array gets bigger, e.g. [[1, 0,1j,0], [0, 1,1,0], [1, 0,-1,0], [1j, 0,-1,0]]. I'm sure this can be fixed easily :)

Answer (score 1):

This works but is ugly and slow:

```
## Defining the cases
B1 = -1*A
B2 = 1j*A
B3 = -1j*A
## Check all cases and replace if necessary
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(B1)):
        C = (A[i]==B1[j]).all()
        if C:
            A[i] = B1[j]/(-1)
        else:
            C = (A[i]==B2[j]).all()
            if C:
                A[i] = B2[j]/(1j)
            else:
                C = (A[i]==B3[j]).all()
                if C:
                    A[i] = B3[j]/(-1j)
A_new = np.unique(A,axis=0)
```

Any other ideas maybe?